# How to run multiple Spring Boot applications easily on Production

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out an easy way to manage many Spring Boot applications on my Production server. Right now I have many fat jars running on different folders where each one has its your own script to start/stop the application and there's an external folder for the configurations (logback, properties, xml). For record those configurations are loaded by command line -Dloader.path to Spring Boot execution.

So how can I avoid conflicts for the same http/https port already running on Production? Does exist any kind of application manager where system administrators could control it? One solution I found was to virtualize Spring Boot applications with Docker, but my environment is Unix Solaris.

Is there any java solution for this scenario?

Comment: Not a perfect solution to your demand because it does not handle setting unique ports, but have a look at Spring boot admin

Comment: Virtualizing your apps in containers is a best practices. Especially for microservices. You should consider doing that.

Comment: I read Spring Boot Admin doc and I have enjoyed the goal, I am gonna try to unify my Spring Cloud Config Server to Spring Boot Admin and get one central point for all applications in execution. I only missed how to manage the http ports in a flexible way.

Comment: If they're microservices you could always start them on a random port (`server.port=0`) and use a service registry like Eureka so you no longer need to know the ports in their consumer.

Comment: Yes,  I agree if it was only services. But the application is UI,  so user must access the http port to navigate into application.

Comment: We plan to use Consul as service registry and proxy the request through nginx. Each spring boot app will run on a different port and nginx will redirect based on url to different ports. To make it dynamic nginx configuration will be reloaded using consul template each time a service registers.

Comment: I tried Consul, but this is not working fine on Intel Solaris 64 bits. It gives addresses exceptions when starting the binary. I also opened an issue for it: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/1627

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) which will give you better control and management when running multiple boot applications. All components of Spring Cloud
might not be useful to you, but few of them will help in port resolution, service rerouting and property maintenance. Along with the above you can also try [SBA](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin).

Along with the above you can also try [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) for UI load balancing and reverse proxy.